# Change MAC of VM on Xen

Tags: debian, linux-networking, xen, xenserver

I have a Xenserver6 and multiple VMs on it - using Xen Orchestra I wanted to change the IP of a VM network device but accidentally shut it down before I could change the MAC. The way the server is set up, it needs the correct virtual MAC to be set to work. Now - I haven't realised that I actually placed my XOA on that server and have only SSH access to the Xen host.

I have tried to use this with the vif UUID of the VM:

xe vif-param-set uuid="....." MAC=.....

but that gives me
Error: Field 'MAC' is read-only.

same error in halted and running state.

how can I modify the MAC of that VM Network device?